# Clickable accordion menu with two fields

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I would love to get some help with my menu.
I've added simple accordion menu to my site, but i need to do one trick. Menu has "Products" title text and arrow to show that product has more submenus.
I would like to separate those fields: 
- when i click on "Products" text it will take me to the linked page
- when i click on rest of "Products" field menu will collapse showing subcategories.
I cannot touch html file, can I do the magic in css or javascript file?

```js
( function( $ ) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('click', function(){
  $(this).removeAttr('href');
  var element = $(this).parent('li');
  if (element.hasClass('open')) {
   element.removeClass('open');
   element.find('li').removeClass('open');
   element.find('ul').slideUp();
  }
  else {
   element.addClass('open');
   element.children('ul').slideDown();
   element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
   element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
   element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
   element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
  }
 });

 $('#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a').append('<span class="holder"></span>');

 (function getColor() {
  var r, g, b;
  var textColor = $('#cssmenu').css('color');
  textColor = textColor.slice(4);
  r = textColor.slice(0, textColor.indexOf(','));
  textColor = textColor.slice(textColor.indexOf(' ') + 1);
  g = textColor.slice(0, textColor.indexOf(','));
  textColor = textColor.slice(textColor.indexOf(' ') + 1);
  b = textColor.slice(0, textColor.indexOf(')'));
  var l = rgbToHsl(r, g, b);
  if (l > 0.7) {
   $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a').css('text-shadow', '0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .35)');
   $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a>span').css('border-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .35)');
  }
  else
  {
   $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a').css('text-shadow', '0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .35)');
   $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a>span').css('border-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .35)');
  }
 })();

 function rgbToHsl(r, g, b) {
     r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
     var max = Math.max(r, g, b), min = Math.min(r, g, b);
     var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

     if(max == min){
         h = s = 0;
     }
     else {
         var d = max - min;
         s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
         switch(max){
             case r: h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0); break;
             case g: h = (b - r) / d + 2; break;
             case b: h = (r - g) / d + 4; break;
         }
         h /= 6;
     }
     return l;
 }
});
} )( jQuery );
```

```css
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: 200px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  display: none;
}
.align-right {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid #1682ba;
  border-right: 1px solid #1682ba;
  border-top: 1px solid #1682ba;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  background: #36aae7;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.open > a {
  color: #eeeeee;
  background: #1fa0e4;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.open > a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1682ba;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1682ba;
}
.holder {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.holder::after,
.holder::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.holder::after {
  top: 17px;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover > span::after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a > span::after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.open > a > span::after {
  border-color: #eeeeee;
}
.holder::before {
  top: 18px;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  border-left: 2px solid;
  border-top-color: inherit;
  border-left-color: inherit;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #32373e;
  border-left: 1px solid #32373e;
  border-right: 1px solid #32373e;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #eeeeee;
  background: #49505a;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.open > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
  background: #424852;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a {
  box-shadow: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li:first-child > a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.open:last-child > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.last.open > a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #32373e;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.open:last-child > ul > li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 11.5px;
  border-top: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  border-left: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.active > a::after,
#cssmenu ul ul li.open > a::after,
#cssmenu ul ul li > a:hover::after {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='active has-sub'><a href='www.IwantToMove.com'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wxv7oao3/1/

Comment: Can you please show us your code?

Comment: You can *touch* the html by appending some DOM elements. I mean, I think the right thing to do is add an `a` wrapping the text, so the user can see the underline when pointing to it.

Comment: @KwS Ctrl+M will let you add a working snippet in your question!

Comment: Thank you did the job! With eyes wide open like a cat from Shrek im waiting for an any helpfull advices! :)

Comment: I posted an answer below, let me know if it helps or works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "e" as a parameter in you click function callback: `'click', function(e) {`

Then, replace `$(this).removeAttr('href');` on line 4 of your JS, with this:

```
e.preventDefault()
if ($(e.target)[0].tagName === 'SPAN') {
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    return; //not really neccesary
}
```

That should do the trick. Essentially, you're capturing whether the click was on the span or not. If it was, go to the URL, otherwise, run the rest of the code.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvincilione/wxv7oao3/6/)

Comment: Looks like good answer, but when trying to add this function to my wordpress site(that's why i couldnt touch html file), it still removes href link. Could it be done without span tag?

Comment: Also, make sure the code is **before** the `$(this).removeAttr('href');` line.

Comment: Can you just give me the link to the site?

Comment: I can only add a class to "products", would it be helpfull to modify sript then?

Comment: I just updated my answer. Try it now. the href was still getting removed when you used the according, but you don't need it to be at all.

Comment: I also updated the JSFiddle, so you can see it in context if you need it.

Comment: Thank You very much for all feedback and Your time, but i think it cannot be done, dont know why. I've added  `e.preventDefault();` but links actually act very weird. When i hover on menu text button it shows link where i want to move on. I can right click and open in new tab, but when i left click accordion menu collapsing and not taking me there, and link is removed - i cannot right click any more...

Comment: Ohh replaced `$(this).removeAttr('href');` now it's not removing href, but not taking me to link site on click :D

Comment: There could be other variables effecting your code when it's on your site. If you need more help with your specific site/setup I can give you my email and we can chat that way.

Answer (score 0):

I've removed some styling and 2nd part from javascript to make it cleaner little more. I also had to replace .holder class that made arrows to border-way arrows:

`#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
    content:"";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    float: right;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
    border-top: 6px solid #5F5F5F;}`

Removed from JS:

`

```
$('#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a').append('<span class="holder"></span>');(function getColor() {
    var r, g, b;
    var textColor = $('#cssmenu').css('color');
    textColor = textColor.slice(4);
    r = textColor.slice(0, textColor.indexOf(','));
    textColor = textColor.slice(textColor.indexOf(' ') + 1);
    g = textColor.slice(0, textColor.indexOf(','));
    textColor = textColor.slice(textColor.indexOf(' ') + 1);
    b = textColor.slice(0, textColor.indexOf(')'));
    var l = rgbToHsl(r, g, b);
    if (l > 0.7) {
        $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a').css('text-shadow', '0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .35)');
        $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a>span').css('border-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .35)');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a').css('text-shadow', '0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .35)');
        $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a>span').css('border-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .35)');
    }
})();

function rgbToHsl(r, g, b) {
    r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
    var max = Math.max(r, g, b), min = Math.min(r, g, b);
    var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

    if(max == min){
        h = s = 0;
    }
    else {
        var d = max - min;
        s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
        switch(max){
            case r: h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0); break;
            case g: h = (b - r) / d + 2; break;
            case b: h = (r - g) / d + 4; break;
        }
        h /= 6;
    }
    return l;
}
```

});`

Because .holder class wasnt displayed on wordpress  menu at all, with border-made arrows it looks properly, but im struggling with same problem: 
when i click on menu it expanding istead of taking me to link href,  despite the fact that href isnt removed anymore.
Updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ja8qy497/

And SS from the moment i click on menu item that has submenus
http://postimg.org/image/4blbyaqtf/

Answer (score -1):

re-order your script, first prepend .holder to .has-sub list item

```
$('#cssmenu li.has-sub').prepend('<span class="holder"></span>');
```

then change your jQuery selector

```
$('#cssmenu li.has-sub > .holder').on('click', this, function(){
```

make changes in your css like

```
.holder {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 10px;
}
.holder::after,
.holder::before {
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    right: 10px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.holder::before {
    top: 11px;
    border-top: 2px solid;
    border-left: 2px solid;
    border-top-color: inherit;
    border-left-color: inherit;
}
.holder::after {
    top: 10px;
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu li li .holder::before,
#cssmenu li li .holder::after {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    top: 8px;
}
#cssmenu li li .holder {
     top: 2px;
}
#cssmenu li li .holder::before {
    top: 10px;
}
#cssmenu li li .holder::after {
    top: 9px;
}
```

remove your following css from your file

```
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover > span::after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a > span::after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.open > a > span::after {
    border-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

and you are done

http://jsfiddle.net/wxv7oao3/8/

Comment: I'm glad You took some time to make another solution. That one form Jacques works, but not on my wordpress site. Spend half a night trying to make it work on my site, It didn't removed href link, but wherever  i click, menu just collapses, and not taking me to another site. I will try this solution when i get back home. Hope it works! Thanks again for this one.

Comment: Your solution makes it where the only way the expansion will happen is when you click the arrow. It's the opposite of what the OP wants.

Comment: reviewing all your questions and discussion, what i got is, you want parent "product" text to redirect on new page if text is clicked and expand sub menu if arrow is clicked, for for the "products" text in sub menus it should collapse further sub menu under this. am i getting you properly ? if not please explain again, I will try giving you exact solution.